# How to Sign Apk With JDK 7

Tags: java, android

I have issues with signing Android Apk with JDk 7.

I followed the following 3 steps for signing and zipaligning

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore C:\Android\Equator_Bytes.keystore -alias Equator_Bytes -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000

jarsigner -verbose -keystore C:\Android\Equator_Bytes.keystore C:\Android\Cloudy_Day_unsigned.apk Equator_Bytes

zipalign -v 4 C:\Android\Cloudy_Day_unsigned.apk C:\Android\CloudyDay.apk
```

However the signed apk is not Installable.

I tried Installing JDK 6, I wasn't even able to install it.

Has Anyone ever succeed in signing with JDK 7? Or is their another way to sign and zipalign?

Thanks!!!

Comment: I sign mine all the time on JDK 7 but I use eclipse to sign

Comment: I can't do it in eclipse since i develop in some other tool.

Answer (score 0):

I installed glassfish JDK 6 all problems solved.Though i haven't tried signing or installing With JDK 7 version of glassfish.